# DNS wildcard subdomain configuration on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dns, apache-http-server, wamp, virtual-host

I run a WAMP server on Windows 10, and tried to install a Wordpress multisite network on localhost using subdomains. The main domain defined in VirtualHost works and points to a localhost folder.

But when I try to install the network, it gives me a warning, that the DNS joker (wildcard) for the domain is not properly set.

What should I write in apache conf, and windows hosts file so that any subdomain points to the same localhost directory?

Apache 2 httpd-vhosts.config:

```
# Virtual Hosts
# <VirtualHost *:80>   ServerName localhost   ServerAlias localhost   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local   </Directory> </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>   ServerName sumthin.eu   ServerAlias
*.sumthin.eu   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wp5"   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/wp5/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local   </Directory> </VirtualHost>
```

windows hosts file:

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 sumthin.eu
127.0.0.1 *.sumthin.eu
::1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use wild cards in the `hosts` file - it should be a one to one mapping of IP to host names.

If you want this functionality, you'd need to set up a DNS server with a zone that it is authoritative for.  Use `home.test` as my domain for my similar set up at home.